# Are posts flagged for moderator attention also visible to people having access to moderator tools?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, flags

I am curious to know, are flagged posts only seen by officially designated moderators, or also by people having enough reputation to access moderator tools?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

10k users have such header:

> [image]

They can see the following flags:

- "not an answer"
- "very low quality"
- <s>"it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate"</s> Removed June 2013.  Close/Duplicate flags now go directly to the close vote queue for 3K users and do not appear in the moderator tools header (for both 10K or Diamond mod)

10k users can also see a variety of automatically generated flags that users cannot cast:

- "too many comments" - More than 20 comments posted in the past 3 days
- "duplicate answer"
- "vandalism" - 5 edits to own old posts in a single day, 5 deletions of own posts in a single day
- "excessively long" - Post is excessively long
- "rollback war"

10k users ***cannot*** see the following flags:

- Comment flags
- Spam or Offensive flags
- Anything with a custom message. "other"

---

Furthermore, 10k users cannot see who the flagger is. Only moderators can see that.

Comment: *How* do the 10k users see these flags? Are they shown in the header as they are for diamond mods, or are they found elsewhere?

Comment: or [privilege moderator-tools](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools)

Comment: There's a flag queue that 10k users have access to which contains all these flags. (which I assume is much more comprehensive for moderators)

Comment: @JonW I've never been a mod on any site, so I don't know if we're talking about the same header. But for 10ks, there is an orange (on SO) button at the top bar which goes to the flag queue.

Comment: @JonW 10K+ flag queue is at: /tools/flagged - A flag count in the header only appears if there are a few flags (don't remember the exact numbers), and it's similar to the mod flag count in the header. On SO it's probably on all the time due to the amount of flags, but on smaller sites it's rarely on and 10Kers won't see pending flags unless they visit their flag queue.

Comment: Is this still accurate with the new flagging procedures?  Specifically do 10K users still see "it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate" flags in the header since they now automatically go to the close vote queue?

Comment: @psubsee2003: You're right. Updated.

Comment: Yh, why 5 edits to own posts are considered vandalism? I thought that editing is good because it improves the quality of posts.

Comment: @Matt for historical purposes, I think this edit works better.  Since I don't have 10K anywhere, please fact check me.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Mmmm; up to you. I'm not sure historical notes *should* be retained myself. Old behaviour isn't really relevant to anyone apart from the inquisitive type (and they can find the old behaviour listed on the [recent changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)).

Comment: @Matt I guess my thinking was that someone who isn't aware of the change might be inclined to add it back in or think this post is wrong since it is missing.  At least this way the info is preserved.  I could easily be persuaded it is not necessary though.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Humm, the revision history will show it being removed though; hopefully the would-be-editor would consult that before blindly adding things in. The revision in particular could link to [the relevant post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186955/was-this-flag-lost-somehow/187008#187008). This is what I've seen been done before on MSE.